# TPCH to generate large datasets

Tags: dataset

I was using TPCH to generate large datasets. I have the dbgen and I do understand that we need to set the scaling factor (which decides the size). I was not sure how or where do we need to set the scaling factor?

If we need to set it during run-time, can someone please tell me the exact procedure.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and when I run the dbgen

[image]

it auto pops a cmd window (windows operating system) and after few minutes asks do you want to replace the table say supplier.tbl but no where I am able to find the option to set the size.

P.S. It does generate all the tables such as supplier.tbl, lineitem.tbl etc. after the dbgen runs and completes but I need 500 GB of data and having trouble getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual procedure to run it is:
a. Open cmd (in windows) and go to the Debug folder using cd folderPath
b. Now type debug.exe -vf -s 500 (500 is the size of my dataset in GBs)

Refer the following link for exact and detailed information
http://www.sqlpanda.com/2014/10/tpc-h-217.html